# BigCartel Neat - COLLECTIONS/CATEGORIES on home page

Tags: themes, neat, bigcartel

I'm using NEAT theme at BigCartel, and want to have COLLECTIONS/CATEGORIES as my home page, not the current FEATURED items. There doesn't seem to be a simple way to do that, the simplest option seems to be to make the COLLECTIONS/CATEGORIES page my new home page. Is it possible to simply set a re-direct from the landing page to that page?

Tried contacting support, they said to ask here